# Menubar is not refreshing after sign in or sign out in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My Menubar is not automatically refreshing when I sign in or sign out, but when I refresh the page manually it is refreshing. I tried so many solutions, but still can't solve this.

Please help me to find a solution to this problem.

My code:

```js
// index page
ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>
  <Routes />
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

My Routes.js file

```js
return (
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Menu />  //this is my menubar
            <Switch>
                <BuyerRoutes path = "/myprofile" exact component={ProfileUpdate} />
                <BuyerRoutes path = "/dashboard" exact component={BuyerHome} />

                <SellerRoutes path = "/seller" exact component={SellerHome} />
                <SellerRoutes path = "/addproduct" exact component={AddProduct} />
               
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
```

my auth.js file

```js
 <Route
        {...rest}
        render = {props =>
            isAuthenticate() && isAuthenticate().user.usertype == 1 ? (
                <Component {...props} />
            ) : (
                <Redirect
                    to={{
                        pathname:"/login",
                        state: {from: props.location}
                    }}
                />
            )
        }
    />
```

My menu.js file

```js
{user && user.usertype===0 ?
<Fragment>
  <Link className="dropdown-item" to="/seller" >Home</Link>
  <Link className="dropdown-item" to="/addproduct" >Add Product </Link>
</Fragment>:
<Fragment>
 <Link className="dropdown-item" to="/myprofile" > My Profile</Link>
 <Link className="dropdown-item" to="/dashboard" >  My Orders</Link>
</Fragment>
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Menu` component usage under `<BrowserRouter>` doesn't involve any dynamic props and state. In React, to re-render components dynamically, you should pass dynamic contents via `props`, whose changes will be reflected by re-rendering. That's why your `<Menu>` component is not changing at all while your router is changing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the store state after sign in and sign out. For an example dispatch an action to delete user login state from the store.